# Dragging a radio button performes the action but doesn't set the check

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qradiobutton

I am creating an application that should work on desktop and some mobile platforms.

The following example creates and connects my portrait/landscape buttons, in a group, to a slot, on the release signal.

```
m_landscapeRadio = new QRadioButton(QObject::tr("Landscape "));
m_portraitRadio = new QRadioButton(QObject::tr("Portrait "));
m_orientationGroup.addButton(m_landscapeRadio, 0);
m_orientationGroup.addButton(m_portraitRadio, 1);
m_orientationGroup.setExclusive(true);
m_landscapeRadio->setChecked(true);
connect(&m_orientationGroup, SIGNAL(buttonReleased(int)), this, SLOT(orientationSlot(int)));
```

But I found a weird situation:

Assume landscape button is checked. If I press and drag away from the portrait radio button, the slot action is performed (for the portrait option) but the portrait button is not checked.

I would like the action not to be performed.

For now...

In the `orientationSlot` I test the argument and set the checked value myself... Though I really expected the buttons to know to do that themselves.

But I think it is more expected by users that, if the press a button and change their mind, to be able to drag away from the button and not have the action be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can handle verifying if the check really happened in the action slot, and either check or discard the action depending on how I will think the user experience is better...

If I want the buttons to be checked and to perform the action as well:

```
void MyWidget::orientationSlot(int checked)
{
    if(checked) m_portraitRadio->setChecked(true);
    else        m_landscapeRadio->setChecked(true);

    .... actual actions
}
```

If I want the action not to be performed when the user drags away from the button (my preferred option):

```
void MyWidget::orientationSlot(int checked)
{
    if(m_orientationGroup.checkedId() != checked) return;

    .... actual actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I use QRadioButton and handle mouse button being released event for reacting
>   on radio button being switched. It causes problems altogether with dragging event. I would like to either get the button
>   to be checked, or the action not to be performed.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradiobutton.html

> Whenever a button is switched on or off, it emits the toggled()
>   signal. Connect to this signal if you want to trigger an action each
>   time the button changes state. Use isChecked() to see if a particular
>   button is selected.

Either you connect the radio button to the handler explicitly or the whole group: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonToggled

> void QButtonGroup::buttonToggled(QAbstractButton *button, bool
>   checked)
>
> This signal is emitted when the given button is toggled. checked is
>   true if the button is checked, or false if the button is unchecked.
>
> Note: Signal buttonToggled is overloaded in this class. To connect to
>   this one using the function pointer syntax, you must specify the
>   signal type in a static cast, as shown in this example:

```
connect(buttonGroup, static_cast<void(QButtonGroup::*)
      (QAbstractButton *, bool)>(&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled),
    [=](QAbstractButton *button, bool checked) {

     if (button == m_portraitRadio) {
      // Portrait (un)checked
      if (checked)
      {
         // checked!
      }
     }
     /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I avoid the toggled() signal since the buttons can be set through code.

Comment: I've added button group example. You need to recognize individual button pressed somehow. Maybe using text() method.

Comment: Thanks - I just have figured it out, I can compare the value sent by the group with the button and see if it is indeed checked. If not I will discard the action. It gets ugly with a button group with lots of buttons...